# How to make grep output fit screen's width of characters

Tags: command-line, grep

I frequently end up grepping files with very long lines resulting in pages worth of output for one matching word.

What's a good way to limit the output to only enough characters as the width of my terminal?

I realize this means the matching word *may* not be present in the line.  But I still want context, so filename only is not acceptable.

Comment: It's possible to "crop" text itself via piping to text processing commands, or even `printf`, but `grep` alone doesn't have setting for output width.  What about the colorization of the output ? Do you care about that at all, or  can that be left out ? That may complicate answers a little

Comment: What output do you *need*? you could use `-o` to limit the output to only the matching portion(s) of lines if that is enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this wrapping function, which passes any parameters to grep, then cuts the output to $COLUMNS (or 80, if COLUMNS isn't set):

```
function grepcut() {
  grep "$@" | cut -c1-${COLUMNS:-80}
}
```

Use it like:

```
$ grepcut sometext somefiles
```

or

```
$ set | grepcut LS_COLORS
```

Comment: thanks Jeff. I combined it with `tput` to limit it to the current number of cols in my terminal  `cols=$(tput cols); grep "$@" | cut -c1-${COLUMNS:-$cols}`

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a more complicated approach that gives output you might prefer. 
It works best if you usually search for simple strings
(no regex-special characters)
and use no options (or, at least, use the same option(s) *every* time). 
My `greptrim` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    ("")
        echo "Usage: $0 string [files...]"
        exit 2
        ;;
    (-*)
        echo "This script can't take options."
        exit 2
        ;;
esac
read rows cols <<< $(stty size)
if [ "$cols" = "" ]
then
        cols=80
fi
margin=$(( (cols-${#1}) / 2 ))
grep -o ".\{,$margin\}$1.\{,$margin\}" "${@:2}"
```

- Preliminaries: check that there is a non-null string (pattern) argument,
  and that it is not an option.
- Then we use yet another way to get the number of columns.<sup>1</sup>
- From the width of the screen (number of columns),
  subtract the width of the string argument (`${#1}`, and divide by two. 
  This computes the number of characters that you can have
  to the left and right of the string
  and still have the line fit on the terminal. 
  For example, for a 10-character string on an 80-column screen,
  `margin` will be 35 (because 35+10+35=80).
- The final command looks a little like `grep -o "$@"`,
  but we do `grep -o "$1" "${@:2}"`. 
  `"${@:2}"` is a bashism that means `"$@"`, but starting at `$2` (if any).
- We wrap `$1` with `.\{,$margin\}` — e.g., `.\{,35\}` — before and after. 
  This matches up to 35 of any character,
  so, in total, our pattern matches up to 80 characters,
  with the original `$1` in the middle.
- `-o` means output only the matching text —
  so we output at most 80 characters per line.

I used this sample text:

```
Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary, Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore—
While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping, As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.
“’Tis some visitor,” I muttered, “tapping at my chamber door— Only this and nothing more.”
```

and here’s an example run in an 80-column screen:

```
$ ./greptrim or raven.txt
r many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore—
ently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.
“’Tis some visitor,” I muttered, “tapping at my chamber d
oor— Only this and nothing more.”
```

Note that the string “or” appears six times in the verse:
“f**or**gotten”, “l**or**e”, “do**or**”, “visit**or**”, “do**or**” and “m**or**e”. 
Note that we get the third line of the input twice
because “visit**or**” and “do**or**” are more than 39 characters apart.

More notes:

- Obviously the script could be extended to handle options. 
  It just becomes tricky to figure out which argument is the pattern
  and which one(s) are the file name(s).
- If you always want to use some option(s), like `-i`,
  just add it/them to the `grep` command in the script.
- If you add `-n`, you should subtract 4 or 5 from `cols`.
- You can use the script with a pattern
  that’s more complex than a simple string,
  but the results might be unsatisfactory,
  because a short regex can match a long text segment (or vice versa),
  so the computation of `margin` will be wrong,
  and you might get more (or fewer) than 80 characters per line.
- If you add `-E`,
  you must change the margin regex to `.{,$margin}` (remove the backslashes).
- An optional feature is to change the last line to

  ```
  grep -o ".\{,$margin\}$1.\{,$margin\}" "${@:2}" | grep --color=auto "$1"
  ```

  to highlight the search string:

  [image: same output, but with color]

  Note that the “or” in “forgotten” perfectly lines up with the “or” in “door”. 
  This will happen in general
  for strings that appear more than `margin` characters
  from the beginning of the line.

________
<sup>1</sup> I got `cols` this way (`read rows cols <<< $(stty size)`)

1. to show a different way of doing it, and
2. because I’m working on Cygwin,
   and `tput` isn’t installed, and `COLUMNS` isn’t set.

It is POSIX compliant.